# Check if there are missing arguments in enclosing call using C/Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I need to use function written in C or Rcpp to check if enclosing R call had missing arguments. Is that possible to do? If so how?

Here is what I came up with after reading some R source code.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
void check_missing(SEXP e) {
  Rcpp::Environment env(e);
  Rcpp::CharacterVector names = env.ls(false);
  SEXP unevaluatedArg;
  for(int i=0; i<names.length(); i++){
    std::string name = as<std::string>(names[i]);
    Rcpp::Rcout << "argument - " << name << std::endl;
    SEXP nameSym = Rf_install(name.c_str());
    unevaluatedArg = Rf_findVarInFrame(e, nameSym);
    if (MISSING(unevaluatedArg) || CAR(unevaluatedArg) == R_MissingArg) {
      Rcpp::Rcout << "missing" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}')
f <- function(x, y) {
  check_missing(environment())
}
f()
```

But somehow `MISSING(unevaluatedArg) || CAR(unevaluatedArg) == R_MissingArg` never evaluates to `TRUE`. Is it because I am enumerating the environment? Or what is going wrong?

P.S. I have reasons for doing that in C, rather than using standard `missing`, because in my project `check_missing` needs to be applied to any environment, and here I just gave a simplified case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `if ( unevaluatedArg == R_MissingArg){ ... }`. This slightly modified code works for me:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void check_missing(SEXP e) {
  Rcpp::Environment env(e);
  Rcpp::CharacterVector names = env.ls(false);
  SEXP unevaluatedArg;
  for(int i=0; i<names.length(); i++){
    std::string name = as<std::string>(names[i]);
    Rcpp::Rcout << "argument - " << name << std::endl;
    SEXP nameSym = Rf_install(name.c_str());
    unevaluatedArg = Rf_findVarInFrame(e, nameSym);   
    if ( unevaluatedArg == R_MissingArg) {
      Rcpp::Rcout << "missing" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Giving:

```
> f()
argument - x
missing
argument - y
missing

> f(1)
argument - x
argument - y
missing
```